# javascript MVC structure, map model to rest api

Tags: javascript, rest, model-view-controller, javascript-objects

I am trying to make a model (the M in MVC) in my web application, to understand the concept. I am struggling with the async problem that occurs in my code below:

```
function FruitModel(api) {
    this._api = api;
}

FruitModel.prototype = {
    getFruit: function(fruit_id) {
        $.getJSON(this._api + fruit_id, function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }
}

$(function(){
    var fruits = new FruitModel("/fruit/");
    console.log(fruits.getFruit(123))
});
```

I get that this is wrong because the console.log will happen before the getJSON has finished, be cause of that this is asynchronous. How should I design this instead to prevent the problem?

I suppose that getting the actual data for a front end MVC is to access it from within the model from a RESTapi equal to mine. Is there a preferred solution instead of doing this inside the model as I do?

Comment: use jquery's when, then, done (promise) methods to handle the response correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a callback to the function and execute it when you done with your async code:

```
FruitModel.prototype = {
    getFruit: function(fruit_id,callback) {
        $.getJSON(this._api + fruit_id, function(data){
            callback(data);
        });
    }
}

$(function(){
    var fruits = new FruitModel("/fruit/");
        fruits.getFruit(123, function(data){
           console.log(data);
         });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that problem you can do something like this ( because from `jQuery 1.5` `.getJSON` implements `Promise` interface )

```
function FruitModel(api) {
    this._api = api;
}

FruitModel.prototype = {
    getFruit: function(fruit_id) {
       return $.getJSON(this._api + fruit_id);
    }
}

//Call

fruits.getFruit(123).done(function(data){
  console.log(data);
})
```